# How to make a custom reusable table component with specific logic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-dom

I need to make a reusable table component with the desktop and mobile version.

- If the screen is lower than 720px it'll show the table with div, ul, li and button "load more" at the bottom.
- If the screen is more than 720px it'll show the regular table with tr,td, thead, etc tags and infinite scrolling with loader in the bottom (without load more button)

I need to pass the same data to this components.
The problem is in the different structure for different screens.
My structure looks like this:

```
<TableDesktop loading={loading} anotherprops={anotherprops}>
   {data && data.map(el => <tr key={el.id}><td>{el.id}</td></tr>)}
/* here is the loader for infinite scrolling from TableDesktop 
component*/
</TableDesktop>

<TableMobile loading={loading} anotherprops={anotherprops}>
   {data && data.map(el => <li key={el.id}><td>{el.id}</td></li>)}
/* here is the loader and "load more" button from TableMobile 
component*/
</TableMobile>
```

It's very simplified version. The real jsx structure will be more complicated.
So, how I can make one Table component which take the same data and show the mobile or desktop table depending on the screen size

Answer (score 0):

A simple conditional render should work

```
render() {
if(screen.width >= 720px) {
  return (
    <TableDesktop loading={loading} anotherprops={anotherprops}>
      {data && data.map(el => <tr key={el.id}><td>{el.id}</td></tr>)}
    </TableDesktop>
  )
else {
  return(
    <TableMobile loading={loading} anotherprops={anotherprops}>
       {data && data.map(el => <li key={el.id}><td>{el.id}</td></li>)}
    </TableMobile>
  )
}
```

or, if you need the conditions to be inline you can try this using the ternary operator

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
    {screen.width >= 720px ? 
      <TableDesktop loading={loading} anotherprops={anotherprops}>
        {data && data.map(el => <tr key={el.id}><td>{el.id}</td></tr>)}
      </TableDesktop>
      :
      <TableMobile loading={loading} anotherprops={anotherprops}>
        {data && data.map(el => <li key={el.id}><td>{el.id}</td></li>)}
      </TableMobile>
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if` block to your `render()` function to return what you want.

```
render() {
    if(window.innerWidth > 720) {
        return (<InfiniteLoader />)
    } else {
        return (<LoaderAndButton />)
    }
}
```